# Movie with a character illustrating that the inevitable happens no matter what by dropping a ball down a slope

Tags: identify-this-movie

I think the movie line is pretty famous but can't quite remember.

The speaker talks about some kind of an effect and he drops a ball down the slope and says something inevitable happens no matter what, meaning that the ball will fall to the ground anyway.

And it does.

When the listener tells him that he could have prevented it by catching the ball before it touches the ground the speaker says, "But I didn't."

Well, the actual movie line might be very different, but this is what I can remember.

**UPDATE:** (I'm adding a few more details as others requested)

The movie is in English and I believe it is an American film.
I can't remember the actors. The movie scene where two people are talking is a dark room (and there probably were a few more) and I think a projector was running.

**UPDATE 2:**

I didn't watch the whole movie but that particular scene was cut and played in a TV show or another movie, I can't remember. The time I watched this was around 2009-2010, but I felt that this was somewhat popular a movie scene that it was quoted and played - the effect being explained popular like "butterfly effect" - and maybe produced sometime earlier. (not sure again when)

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like [Minority Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_Report_%28film%29), where Tom Cruise's character John demonstrates predetermination to Colin Farrell's character Danny by rolling a ball along the plexiglass table, which Danny then catches.

> **John:** Why'd you catch that?
>
> **Danny:** Because it was gonna fall.
>
> **John:** You're certain?
>
> **Danny:** Yeah.
>
> **John:** But it didn't fall. You caught it. Preventing it doesn't change the fact that it was going to happen.

It happens in a dark(ish) room with a screen. Here's most of the scene:

P.S. If you're trying to remember *where* you saw it, you can search [this page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181689/movieconnections#featured_in) in the desired year.